# Acceptable to wish someone "happy Eid" before the end of Ramadan?

Tags: ramadan, eid, culture

Is wishing a Muslim person "happy Eid" before the day of Eid al-Fitr something which is done in Islamic culture?

In my case, I have a work-friend who I typically see once a week at work. I am *fairly certain* they are fasting for Ramadan. Would it be better to wish them "happy Eid" a few days **before**, or a few days **after** June 15th? Or is there no difference?

As I understand it, Eid al-Fitr is a celebration of *the end* of a month of fasting, so I wasn't sure if it would be appropriate to congratulate them on the conclusion of the month while they are *still fasting*.

Comment: It might not make sense to wish him Happy Eid before (because Eid is a celebration **of** not just at the end of a successful month of fasting) since he is still fasting, but Islamically I don't believe there are any rules about when you can and cannot wish Happy Eid because as far as I know it (the greeting) is not a religiously sanctioned thing.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulating on a "Eid" in Islam is fine as long as it is in Islam(not a birthday or related)

But if you're asking culturally, then Eid: The last day he fasts in is still in Ramadan, as soon as the sun sets and the "Maghrib" prayer is up, it is declared that Ramadan is over and that day is the Eid. so if you're going to congratulate him at a time, make it either at the night after he finishes his last day of fasting or the next day(not night; because the "day" starts at sunset and ends at the same time of the next day[that's why the *day* he fasts in is Ramadan but the night isn't])

Answer (score 1):

I think by doing so you will bring smile for your friend so say it Happy Eid in advance.

It is the same "Eidun Sa'eed" in English.

You and your friend know that you are not going to meat again before that, sure he will be happy.

> Verse 2:185 ... Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you
>   hardship ..